# PHP reserved method names

Tags: php, oop, methods, reserved-words

Other than those described by http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php, are there any method names I shouldn't use?  For instance, can I make a method `public function echo($x)` and use it as `$this->echo('Hello');`?

EDIT>  Evidently, I can't use `echo` because it is a  language constructs, but could use `min`.  Following doesn't result in an error.

```
<?php
  class myClass {
      public function min($x){echo(min($x));}
  }

  $obj=new myClass();
  $obj->min(array(5,3,6,3));
?>
```

Comment: Doesn't it mean that you're re-declaring a function?
BTW, you can always try and look for errors ;)

Comment: @OfirBaruch  I did look for errors.  Please see my edited original post.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use language construct names in a classes regarding namespaces, while you can use built-in function names in namespace. A namespace in this case is a method of a class.

```
$foo = new Foo();

$foo->array_key_exists(); // Good
$foo->isset(); // Fatal error, since isset() a language construct
$foo->include(); // Also fatal error
```

The reason you don't get a fatal error when using `min()` is because its a built-in function.

Generally it's considered bad practice using built-in names in your own implementations because that might confuse another developers that will be reading your code in future.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd bothered actually trying:

```
php > class foo { function echo($bar) { print($bar); } }
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in php shell code on line 1
```

Comment: I actually did try, but am using the function name `min()`, and didn't get an error.  Please see my original post.  Thanks

Comment: because `$foo->min()` is obviously not the built-in PHP `min()` function. it's a method of whatever class $foo is in. `min()` by itself, cannot be overriden/replaced, because it's a core PHP function. `echo` is NOT a function. it's a language construct and cannot be used in any other context except for "do some output". it'd be like trying to do `function function()`

Comment: Ah, I see that `echo` is in the reserved words.  Was a bad example in my post!  So, using methods and not language constructs is okay, right?